# @types/jquery error 'jQuery' is undefined

Tags: jquery, typescript2.0

I created a TypeScript project in VS 2015 (HTML Application with TypeScript)

Package:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40"
   }
}
```

ts.config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "umd",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [ "jquery" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

test.ts:

```
jQuery(document).ready(() => {}
```

When I run the app, it throws  'jQuery' is undefined.

What's the problem?

Note: There is @types folder in node_modules folder and code Reflection works fine (e.g. type jquery. it prompt ajax, bind etc...

Comment: Does my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to add `import $ from 'jquery'` command at the top line of your code